# FraudTrackr For Magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, php

Does Magento have any plugins that would allow me to use FraudTrackr?  Or would that require a custom plugin to be created?

How difficult would this API be to use?  https://www.fraudtrackr.com/developer-api.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Magento have any plugins that would allow me to use FraudTrackr?

A quick search on Magento Connect yields no results

> Or would that require a custom plugin to be created?

Yes

> How difficult would this API be to use? https://www.fraudtrackr.com/developer-api.php

This depends on your level of efficiency in php / Magento. It comes with documentation so that's a bonus and the number of request types and variables look manageable.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, that's exactly the information I was looking for :)

Comment: This would make a great community extension.